# Argument not specified for parameter and character cannot be used here in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried to convert from c# to vb.net but there was an error. Is there a solution and I use visual studio 2010.
I post full code

thanks
jack

```
'In the insert form:
       Public Sub New(ByVal f2 As Form2)
            InitializeComponent()
            frm2 = f2
        End Sub

        Public Delegate Sub UpdateDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As UpdateEventArgs)
        Public Event UpdateEventHandler As UpdateDelegate
        Private frm2 As Form2

        Public Class UpdateEventArgs
            Inherits EventArgs

            Public Property Data() As String
        End Class

        Protected Sub raiseUpdate()
            Dim args As New UpdateEventArgs()
            UpdateEventHandlerEvent?.Invoke(Me, args) 'this error Argument not specified for parameter and character cannot be used
        End Sub

        Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Dim sqlCon As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\v-baf\OneDrive\MyWork\MyWinFrm\WinFormApplication20170302\WinFormApplication20170517+\DB\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

            Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlCon)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1(Character, Level, Clan) values('" & textBox2.Text & "','" & textBox3.Text & "','" & textBox4.Text & "')"
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
            raiseUpdate()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Where does `UpdateEventHandlerEvent` come from?

Comment: Which converter did you use?

Comment: @CaiusJard , I use instant vb tangible software

Comment: Or upgrade your decades old IDE to enjoy bucket loads of new features and wonderful development experiences

Comment: @CaiusJard `If UpdateEventHandler IsNot Nothing Then UpdateEventHandler.Invoke(Me, args)`  errror Public Event UpdateEventHandler(sender As Object, args As UpdateEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar , come from insert form (form3)

Comment: @CaiusJard , Okay I post full code

Comment: What's the error you're talking about ? On another note, `UpdateEventHandlerEvent` doesn't seem to be a property in the full code you posted.

Comment: @PaulKaram , I've updated in which line code is error

Comment: @PaulKaram I was suddenly reminded it's an automagical created by VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use either:

```
RaiseEvent UpdateEventHandler(Me, args)
```

Or:

```
If UpdateEventHandlerEvent IsNot Nothing Then UpdateEventHandlerEvent.Invoke(Me, args)
```

(I suspect your ancient VB doesn't understand the `?.` syntax the converter has generated)

Your name of your event could do with some improvement; consider calling it something like:

```
Public Event DataInserted As ...
```

Also, complete aside, read http://bobby-tables.com as a matter of urgency and never again write an SQL like you have done there; it enables the number one easy way to hack a system that has a database

Comment: I have the latest post maybe you can help me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480133/change-format-date-and-can-update-in-textbox-with-blank-or-zero-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment126342499_71480133)