# change format date and can update in textbox with blank or zero in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, textbox

I wanted to change the date format in the textbox to the format "dd-mmm-yy" but it did not work when in datagridview did not appear the date with the time and also I could not update in the textbox with blank and zero which caused the error "data type error". if I do not perform sql command for update in the "DATE" field then do not cause error. I use visual studio 2010
so the problem in the date column and if I update without a date column then it runs perfectly. Problem error : syntax error in update statement
thanks
jack
[image: form display gridview and textbox]
[image: error syntax]

```
  Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim cn As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Private connectionString As String
    Private con As OleDbConnection
    Private cmd As OleDbCommand
    Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private sql As String
    Public x As Integer
    Public Sub dbConnection()
        connectionString = CStr(cn)
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        txtCODE.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        DateTimePicker1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
NumericUpDown1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
       
    End Sub
    Private Sub FillDataGridView()
        Try
            Dim query = "select CODE,DTE,QTY FROM EXAMPLE"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(CStr(cn))
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Try
            dbConnection()
            x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
            'sql = "UPDATE EXAMPLE SET QTY=? WHERE CODE=?"
            sql = "UPDATE EXAMPLE SET DTE=?,QTY=? WHERE CODE=?"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("DTE", OleDbType.Date)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("QTY", OleDbType.Numeric)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("CODE", OleDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters("DTE").Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            cmd.Parameters("QTY").Value = NumericUpDown1.Value
            cmd.Parameters("CODE").Value = txtCODE.Text

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated...", "Update")
            con.Close()
            FillDataGridView()
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillDataGridView()
    End Sub
```

[image: syntax error in update statement]
[image: error CONVERSION]

Comment: If the column DPRSOBNET in the database is a DateTime type, and it is read into your program it into a DataTable, the type can be preserved. Then you would use the datatable as the source for the DGV: [How to: Bind data to the Windows Forms DataGridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)....

Comment: ... For the custom formatting: [How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Once that is done, you will be able to get the selected data as a DateTime, and use parameters to pass the data with the query and it will all work properly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , 
here I mean date format in textbox not in datagridview. Because in datagridview the date format is correct

Comment: If the value in the DGV came from a DateTime that you could still access, it would be trivial to format it as required in the TextBox. It would also be trivial to pass the value back to the database for queries. You need to note that there is a difference between a date and the string representation of a date.

Comment: Use parameters (I mentioned it in the last question: https://Bobby-Tables.com) and most of your problems will go away. Use the dataset designer to design your data access and data binding to get your data to show in grids and textboxes and probably all the rest of the problems will go away :)

Comment: @CaiusJard , I've updated the full sample code and screenshots maybe you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL line must be written like:

```
sql = "UPDATE EXAMPLE SET DATE=@d,QTY=@q WHERE CODE=@c"
```

You set the values of these @xxx by adding more code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", dtpDATE.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q", nudQTY.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", txtCODE.Text)
```

Change your date time TextBox to be a datetimepicker instead. Instead of using textboxes for numeric values, use a NumericUpDown instead.

You *must* call `AddWithValue("@xxx"...` in the same order as the @xxx appear in the SQL. Access ignores the names and looks at the order Parameters appear in the SQL so it is important to call AWV on the same order. One day when you upgrade o using a different database it will support the name part of the parameter so you can add your values in any order but right now on access, order is important

You must write your SQL like I've shown. Never, ever do what you were doing before. Never use string concatenation to build a user-supplied data value into an SQL statement. It makes your program trivial to hack into. This might not matter while you're writing a tiny app to index grandma's record collection but it must never be done on any [system of importance such as one used by many people](https://time.com/4130704/vtech-hack-childrens-toys/?amp=true)

Comment: thanks replies from but still errors and I have updated the answer code from you and screenshot error and another what if I want to change the value to blank or zero in the date and qty column?

Comment: You've put the cmd.Parameters calls *before* you made `cmd = New ...`. You should turn on Option Explicit (and Option Strivt while you're at it) - it would help prevent such a mistake

Comment: for explicit option and strict option I have made on and also code I have also updated according to your recommendation but there is an error syntax error in update statement

Comment: Oof, I've just noticed the mention of dBase 4 in the conn str - I wouldn't use such an ancient DB for new development, but if you're stuck with it for some reason (?) we might ahve to find a way to make it work - I'm now wondering if that's the issue. Try changing the sql to `UPDATE EXAMPLE SET DATE=?, QTY=? WHERE CODE=?`

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Hmm.. bit more of a barrel scrape - I've never used dBase - https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1132555 seems to describe a situation similar to yours - select works but update doesn't and the proposed update syntax is nothing like regular SQL, or anything I've experienced. Do you *have* to use dBase?

Comment: Maybe you have another solution and yes I have to use the dbase/dbf database because my client is still using the program with the dbf database

Comment: By all means try some variations on the syntax mentioned in that tektips thread e.g. `USE EXAMPLE REPLACE ALL DATE WITH ? FOR NMBRID = ?` etc but I think you might have reached the limit of my ability to help; you're using a database system that is 34 years old, and I've never seen it - you'd do well to convince the client to upgrade

Comment: I've updated code using command parameters if I run without updates for in the date column then it runs perfectly with the process and updates directly in the database. if I run an update with it in the date column then an error `error:syntax in update statement` appears

Comment: if I use replace all as you suggest then in the position where the line code and how is the code?

Comment: I've already succeeded this because of your help and I changed the dbf field name example from "DATE" to "DTE". I need help with how to solve if the contents of the record are empty in the "DTE" column and the "QTY" column so that there is no conversion error and how to use DateTimePicker to update to zero or blank and also how numericupdown to become blank? you can update your answer so I can mark the solution for you

Comment: Sounds like a wise decision; just read the earlier comment about a syntax error on Date- I didn't realize it was a problem because you used it in the SELECT without issue, but as a going-forward thing you should always try to avoid calling any column the same as a sql reserved word - it's easy enough to do, as names that are reserved words like "date" are a bit bland - transactiondate, orderdate, CreatedDate etc are better and not reserved

Comment: For questions like how to put a blank in an up down or a date picker, I tend to use a checkbox saying "none" or similar. When the checkbox is ticked, hide the datepicker and change the query so it does a `If noDateCheckBox.Checked Then cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", DbNull.Value) Else cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", dtpXyz.Value)` type thing. I've no idea if db4 will accept DBNull.Value/I'm not sure what youd put for blank

Comment: `DateTimePicker1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.date.ToString()` Public member 'date' on type 'DBNull' not found.>> Because there is an empty in the record on my CellDoubleClick. `NumericUpDown1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString()` Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid. >> Because there is an empty in the record on my CellDoubleClick. So how's the code solution?

Comment: Check the `DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value`  for being equal to DBNull.Value - if it is, hide the dtp etc and set the checkbox to checked

Comment: `   If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString()) Then
            DateTimePicker1 = CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
        Else
            DateTimePicker1 = String.Empty 
        End If` >> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker

Comment: `        Dim DateTimePicker1 As String
        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString()) Then
            DateTimePicker1 = CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString())
        Else
            DateTimePicker1 = String.Empty
        End If`  if I make it like that when I double click cell gridview does not appear in numericupdown Or I was wrong in the code.